# App inside docker container can't be accessed from outside of the computer

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, docker-engine

I'm using a **windows machine with WSL2**. Docker Desktop and Docker Engine installed. I've been working on some projects using Docker Desktop for Windows that involve allowing users to connect from other devices. This hasn't been a problem until I've decided to switch to **Docker Engine via WSL2**. When I run a container on Docker Engine, it can only be accessed from localhost:port, not from machine_ip:port. This is the command I'm using to run an [ignition](https://inductiveautomation.com/ignition/) container, which works fine on Docker Desktop but not so fine on Docker Engine:

```
docker run --name ignition -p 8085:8088 inductiveautomation/ignition:latest
```

Is there any reason preventing the ports from "opening" when using Engine vs Desktop?

I tried changing the port to
`-p 0.0.0.0:8085:8088` and setting `-h 0.0.0.0`. I also tried running a [shiny app](https://posit.co/products/open-source/shinyserver/) to see if the error had something to do with ignition but there was no success. Every container I run on Docker Engine only works on locahost.

I've also made sure to stop and even delete the containers I created on Docker Desktop with conflicting ports. Also, not sure if this is unrelated but when I start the WSL2 console and type `docker context ps` I see the containers running on Docker Engine, but if I start Docker Desktop and run the command, I see the Docker Desktop containers. I've checked the active context for both scenarios using `docker context ls` and the default context is always the active one (not desktop-linux nor desktop-windows).